Dynamically retrieve dataset from the Azure Blob storage and write to database
I am trying to create a workflow in FME where I read an Excel file directly from an Azure Blob Storage container, without storing the file locally. My goal is to process the data from the file in FME and then write it to another destination.
How can I configure the FeatureReader in FME to work directly with a file (for example from the AzureBlobStorageConnector)?
Are there any alternative methods to read and process an Excel file directly from Azure Blob Storage without storing the file locally?
AzureBlobStorageConnector: With this I have retrieved the list with the url and name of the file. This works fine, but i am struggling to know how to use this to retrieve the excel.
FeatureReader: I am trying to use the FeatureReader to read the file directly from the Azure Blob storage but i do not know how to set te parameters.
For the Reader Format I have chosen Excel.
For the Dataset parameter I have tried to bind the output of the AzureBlobStorageConnector (for example via a parameter like @Value(url)).

'Are there any alternative methods to read and process an Excel file directly from Azure Blob Storage without storing the file locally?' - Did you try Azure Data factory?

For this project I have to use FME

As per this Documentation,

AzureBlobStorageConnector does not support moving the files from one storage to another storage directly.

You can use FeatureReader by which you can copy the files from one storage account to another without using AzureBlobStorageConnector and also there is no need of local copy.
As per this answer by @sigtil,

After using required format file, click on the down arrow of the Dataset and select File from web option. Then, select Browse Microsoft Azure Blob storage option and select your file.

After reading the file, you can make use of FeatureWriter to write the file to another Blob storage account.
You can go through this documentation to know more about this.
